The blender crashes when I click on the "shading" tab
The blender crashes when I click on the "shading" tab. RX580 video card, i7-3770 processor, 8GB RAM. Help please.

Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see Where to Report a Bug. If the issue is in or caused by a third party addon, please report it to the addon author instead.
